# What's the difference between apt-get install and apt-get build-dep?

Tags: apt

On the [apt-get man's page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get), one can find this:

> **install pkg(s)**
>   This option is followed by one or more packages desired
>   for installation. Each package is a package name, not a fully
>   qualified filename (for instance, in a Fedora Core system, glibc would
>   be the argument provided, not glibc-2.4.8.i686.rpm).
>   **All packages required by the package(s) specified for installation
>   will also be retrieved and installed**.
>   [...]
>
> **build-dep source_pkg**
>   Causes apt-get to install/remove packages in an
>   **attempt to satisfy the build dependencies** for a source package.

It sounds like both of those are trying to satisfy dependencies, but I had different results while [installing `matplotlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843560/1030960) with each of those: `apt-get intall` didn't work with my subsequent `pip install matplotlib` in my virtualenv, while `apt-get build-dep` did*.

`*` Yeah, I needed to install `matplotlib` in a venv, but pip couldn't resolve some of the dependencies, so I lazily used apt in order to solve it

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The short version.

```
apt-get install
```

installs a new package, automatically resolving and downloading dependent packages.  If package is installed then try to upgrade to latest version.

```
apt-get build-dep
```

Causes apt-get to install/remove packages in an attempt to satisfy the build dependencies for a source package.

The command `sudo apt-get build-dep packagename` means to install all dependencies for 'packagename' so that I can build it". So build-dep is an apt-get command just like install, remove, update, etc.

The `build-dep` command searches the local repositories in the system and install the build dependencies for package. If the package does not exists in the local repository it will return an error code.

For installing matplotlib see [To Install matplotlib on Ubuntu](http://joat-programmer.blogspot.com/2012/11/install-matplotlib-on-ubuntu-1210-for.html)

<sup>Source:ManPage & Ravi Saive</sup>

Comment: TL;DR: `apt-get build-dep packagename` will install all files needed to *rebuild* the `packagename` from the source. You can acquire source with `apt-get source packagename` and re-build it with `cd packagename* && debuild`. Nowadays you usually want to use `mk-build-deps packagename` instead to that you can easily uninstall the packages only needed for building.

Answer (score 30):

The difference is whether the dependencies are needed at **runtime** as opposed to **at buildtime**.

For instance, maybe I'm building a binary which uses openssl. At **build** time I would need the openssl header files, which are in `libssl-dev`. I would then list this as a `Build-Depends`.

However, the resulting binary and package don't need the header and other development files, so at **install** time I don't need `libssl-dev`. It wouldn't be in `Depends`, then. But `libssl`, the runtime library my binary linked against, would need to be in `Depends`.

The man sections you quoted indicate this (it talks about "satisfy the **build** dependencies" of a package), but without prior knowledge of when Build-Depends are used, this can be confusing.

Have a look at the Debian policy guide for definitions of control file fields:

http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html

here's the section on Build-Depends. Note it's under the "dependencies for **source** packages" header:

http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-sourcebinarydeps

And this one talks about Depends. Note its' under the **Binary packages** header:

http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-binarydeps

Comment: Thanks. It seems I would need to build-dep for building a library from source.. according to your descript.