# How to install delegate libraries for Image Magick 7.0.7

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, compiling, imagemagick

I built Image Magick 7.0.7 from source on my Ubuntu 18.04 system.* Typing `magick identify -version` into the terminal now returns

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-37 Q16 x86_64 2018-05-31 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in):
```

It has no delegates installed, and now I need to get it to work with  common file types like .jpg, .png, and .tif. I did use `./configure --enable-shared`, but nonetheless, those formats are missing. However, clearly there exist shared libraries on my system for those.

The Delegate Library Configuration entries for the formats I'm most concerned about is confusing:

```
  JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes     no
  OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes      no
  PNG               --with-png=yes      no
  TIFF              --with-tiff=yes     no
```

The 2nd row seems to show it tried to install those formats, but the last row seems to show no installation occurred. I thus don't know what to do with this information.

Can I install the missing delegates from the [delegate packages they have available](https://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/)?

Edit: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746195/364597) provides a partial solution, but still a lot of delegates are missing, including the one I really need, TIFF. The question the answer is for shows a lot of effort to install from the delegate library maintained by Image Magick with no success, which is discouraging. Installing from there still seems like the best option at this point, if someone has advice on that.

---

<sub>*(It fails 2 tests when `make check` is run so it executes its test suite, and I've opened an issue on their GitHub repo as the log requests.)</sub>

Comment: I think it mostly depends on what development libraries are detected during the build configuration (`./configure`) step - did you *"verify that this configuration matches your expectations."* as suggested?

Comment: Alright, i found that part of the output after ./configure, but then what  - are the arguments after each file format what can be used to run configure again with that option activated?

Comment: The way I interpret it, `--with-foo=yes     no` means that the feature was requested (either with an explicit `--with-foo=yes` on the command line, or because the feature is enabled by default) but is not going to get built in because the necessary development headers / libraries were not detected.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right, now that i've read more. However i don't know where to put the delegate downloads and how to point to them so they get configured properly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you have simply *skipped* some of the required Bionic Beaver development libraries. Once these are installed you should be good to go!

**1. 'Development' Files:**

Easiest way to generate the required list of development libraries is to make sure you have the 'Sources' box ticked in 'Software & Updates' and then run the following command from a Terminal:

```
apt-get -s build-dep imagemagick
```

This *simulated run* (-s) will give you an eye-watering number of files to install (240mb download on a clean Bionic Beaver install). I have done this already for you so simply run the following *single command* to load up the required development files:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev build-essential chrpath \
cm-super-minimal debhelper dh-autoreconf dh-exec dh-strip-nondeterminism doxygen \
doxygen-latex dpkg-dev fonts-lmodern g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 graphviz \
icu-devtools libann0 libasan4 libatomic1 libbz2-dev libc-dev-bin libc6-dev \
libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcdt5 libcgraph6 libcilkrts5 \
libclang1-6.0 libdjvulibre-dev libexif-dev libexpat1-dev libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev \
libfftw3-long3 libfftw3-quad3 libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfontconfig1-dev \
libfreetype6-dev libgcc-7-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin \
libgraphite2-dev libgts-0.7-5 libgvc6 libgvpr2 libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 \
libice-dev libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libilmbase-dev \
libitm1 libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblab-gamut1 \
liblcms2-dev liblqr-1-0-dev liblsan0 libltdl-dev liblzma-dev libmime-charset-perl \
libmpx2 libopenexr-dev libpango1.0-dev libpathplan4 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev \
libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libperl-dev libpixman-1-dev libpng-dev libpotrace0 \
libptexenc1 libpthread-stubs0-dev libpython-stdlib libquadmath0 librsvg2-bin \
librsvg2-dev libsigsegv2 libsm-dev libsombok3 libstdc++-7-dev libsynctex1 \
libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 libtiff-dev libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5 libtool libtool-bin \
libtsan0 libubsan0 libunicode-linebreak-perl libwmf-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev \
libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxft-dev \
libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxrender-dev libxt-dev libzzip-0-13 linux-libc-dev m4 \
make pkg-config pkg-kde-tools po-debconf preview-latex-style python python-minimal \
python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 tex-common \
texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils \
texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra \
texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pictures x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev \
x11proto-xext-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xsltproc xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
```

On top of these development files we can add a few more to round out the ImageMagick installation, checkinstall to assist in packaging and a few more -dev files to build some delegates not seen in the standard Ubuntu package. The following is again *a single command*:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall libwebp-dev libopenjp2-7-dev librsvg2-dev \
libde265-dev libheif-dev
```

**2. Download , compile & install:**

Then run the following *single command* to download the latest ImageMagick and successfully build it:

```
mkdir $HOME/imagemagick_build && cd $HOME/imagemagick_build && \
wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-7.0.7-37.tar.bz2 && \
tar xvf ImageMagick-7.0.7-37.tar.bz2 && cd ImageMagick-7.0.7-37 && \
./configure --with-rsvg && make && \
sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/imagemagick_build" \
     --pkgname imagemagick --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default \
     --pkgversion "7.0.7-37" && \
make distclean && sudo ldconfig
```

Where I have indicated: `./configure --with-rsvg && make` you can substantially speed up the compile by adding something like the following: `./configure --with-rsvg && make -j 4`, adding in an integer commensurate with the number of cores available from your processor...

**3. Test the installation:**

Testing this version reveals your required delegates *safely installed*:

```
andrew@ilium:~$ identify --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-37 Q16 x86_64 2018-06-01 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng 
jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
andrew@ilium:~$
```

And now you have the very latest ImageMagick installed on Bionic Beaver with all of the delegates that you required and a few extra ones for good measure:).

Comment: Wow, for me adding these libraries involved downloading 546 MB.  But it's worth it, i need this and didn't want to get into learning vips. A bit of a note - `identify version` gives me data on ImageMagick 6.9.7-4, which is still installed on the system. `magick identify -version` returned the data for 7.0.7-37.

Comment: @kimholder Remove the older version would be best :). Ubuntu is not a particularly rich compiling environment by default hence the hefty downloads! And sounds like you are on the way with the newest version + all of the delegates so this is great news! I will rummage around a little further with heic delegate which intrigues me ....

Comment: There are some packages I sometimes try to install, that try to pull in `texlive` and the related stuff, just like it's happening here in point 1. I always shy away from that because I have the newest version of `texlive` installed from CTAN. Why does it try to do that and will it conflict with my installation if I let it do it?

Comment: Works like a charm. Did this to include webp format in delegates. I had to change the download address, the tar, and the version as follows: 'wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz' - 'tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz' Change pkgversion to: '--pkgversion "7.1.0-8"' or whatever version number is unpacked by the tar. Aside from that, it all worked just as @andrew.46 outlines.

Answer (score 2):

The approach suggested by @andrew-46 is fine, it was useful to understand **how Install ImageMagick with delegates on Ubuntu 20.04**

I know that the answer was related to 18.04 but maybe can be useful for someone else.

In particular my goal was to install it into a docker image, this is how I did:

```
# Install ImageMagick build dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq &&\
  apt-get install -y -qq \
  chrpath debhelper dh-exec dpkg-dev g++ ghostscript gsfonts libbz2-dev \
  libdjvulibre-dev libexif-dev libfftw3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev \
  libjpeg-dev liblcms2-dev liblqr-1-0-dev libltdl-dev liblzma-dev libopenexr-dev \
  libpango1.0-dev libperl-dev libpng-dev librsvg2-bin librsvg2-dev libtiff-dev libwebp-dev \
  libwmf-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxml2-dev libxt-dev pkg-config pkg-kde-tools zlib1g-dev
# Install ImageMagick Platform-independent build dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq &&\
  apt-get install -y -qq \
  doxygen doxygen-latex graphviz jdupes libxml2-utils xsltproc
# Install and Configure ImageMagick
RUN wget https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/ImageMagick-7.1.0-4.tar.gz -P /opt
RUN tar -xvzf /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-4.tar.gz -C /opt
RUN /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-4/configure --with-modules --enable-shared
RUN make -j 2 /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-4
RUN make install /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-4/
RUN make distclean
RUN ldconfig /usr/local/lib
RUN rm /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-4.tar.gz
```

I found dependencies list here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/imagemagick

Comment: What is the advantage to installing dependencies manually as compared to `apt-get build-dep imagemagick` or `mk-build-deps` ?

Comment: Dependencies are different from delegates. Here we need specific delegates. See more at https://askubuntu.com/questions/324845/whats-the-difference-between-apt-get-install-and-apt-get-build-dep

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my ImageMagick install and used andrew.46's really helpful answer above as the basis of my solution.

Andrew's solution failed for me at the `make` stage as the `.heic` delegate package didn't compile correctly, causing the whole process to fail. There are two solutions if this happens to you - compile without `.heic` support if you don't need to use iphone images, or install the necessary packages for the heic delegate package.

**1 'Development' files**

Exactly follow andrew.46 answer above.

**2 Optional - Download packages to compile .heic delegate**

I used the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131996/problems-with-compiling-imagemagick-with-heic) as the basis for my solution. You need to install the libde265 and libheif packages.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick libde265 libheif
$ cd /usr/src/ 
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/strukturag/libde265.git  
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/strukturag/libheif.git 
$ cd libde265/ 
$ sudo ./autogen.sh 
$ sudo ./configure 
$ sudo make –j4  
$ sudo make install 
$ cd /usr/src/libheif/ 
$ sudo ./autogen.sh 
$ sudo ./configure 
$ sudo make –j4  
$ sudo make install
```

**3 Download, compile and install**

You can break the commands in andrew's answer to smaller chunks to see what's going on if helpful. Just run parts of the command in between `&&' speperately. (I didn't actually realise you could use && to join terminal commands together - it's a trick I'm going to use a lot more now.)

The following worked for me:

```
$ mkdir $HOME/imagemagick_build && cd $HOME/imagemagick_build
$ wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ tar xvf ImageMagick-7*
$ ./configure --with-rsvg
$ make -j4
$ sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/imagemagick_build" \
     --pkgname imagemagick --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default \
     --pkgversion "7.0.10-14"
$ make distclean && sudo ldconfig
```

Note that this should work with the latest version of ImageMagick (just make sure you replace `--pkgversion "7.0.10-14" with whatever version you've downloaded.

If you didn't follow step 2 above, you have to configure ImageMagick without the heic delegate. Just run `./configure --with-rsvg --with-heic=no` and you won't have .heic delegate but the compilation will work.

**4 verify version**

type `identify -version` in the terminal to check the install. You should have the full list of delegates.

```
$ identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-14 Q16 x86_64 2020-05-24 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Comment: This works, but every other day I have to rerun "sudo ldconfig" because bash starts using a wrong path for "convert" and I get: convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory