# How to install libheif-dev on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, imagemagick

For a longtime I try to get Imagemagick running on my Ubuntu 18.04. After a alot of searching and reading I am stuck now installing libheif-dev.
It seems there is an easy solution for 20.04 LTS:

https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/1511

But on 18.04 LTS I am stuck. Can somebody help me how to install libheif-dev?

Te error I get is:

```
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/m0ps/Desktop/video2/BSgen/ImageMagick-7.0.11-4'
  CCLD     utilities/magick
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_image_set_raw_color_profile'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_have_decoder_for_format'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_context_add_exif_metadata'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_image_handle_get_luma_bits_per_pixel'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_context_add_XMP_metadata'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_image_handle_get_raw_color_profile_size'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_image_handle_get_raw_color_profile'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_have_encoder_for_format'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_context_read_from_memory_without_copy'
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `heif_has_compatible_brand'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:8043: recipe for target 'utilities/magick' failed
make[1]: *** [utilities/magick] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/m0ps/Desktop/video2/BSgen/ImageMagick-7.0.11-4'
Makefile:6120: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed libheif as described here: [Problems with compiling ImageMagick with heic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131996/problems-with-compiling-imagemagick-with-heic)

libheif is installed but with libheif there is a problem:

```
    (base) m0ps@m0ps:/usr/local/lib$ pkg-config libheif --modversion
1.11.0
(base) m0ps@m0ps:/usr/local/lib$ pkg-config libheif-dev --modversion
Package libheif-dev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libheif-dev.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libheif-dev' found
```

I was searching for 'libheif-dev.pc' but did not find in on my machine

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is there a reason you can not update to 20.04 where you say it works?

Comment: You haven't said what problem you get on installing it; I see `libheif-dev | 1.1.0-2       | bionic/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` so assuming you're using one of those *architectures* what error message are you getting?  (do you have 'universe' enabled?)

Comment: this is NO DUBLICATE! The question is not answered yet! The other answer did not solve my problem!! Please remove the "duplicate" remark. I am still hoping for help

Comment: Finally I found a workaround. Since I do not need heif support I installed imagemagick as described here: https://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-on-debian-ubuntu/ but instead of running the command `./configure` i used `./configure --with-heic=no` now I can use imagemagick :)